# how to compile java.class file

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

lets say i have a file MainClass.class which i think contains the following code

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    App app = new App(5,17);
    app.Answer();

}
}
```

based on the MainClass.class i wrote a simple class called App.java, witch add 2 numbers.

```
public class App {
private int num1;
private int num2;
private int sum;

public App(int n1, int n2){
    num1=n1;
    num2=n2;
}

public void Answer(){
    sum=num1+num2;
    System.out.println("The sum of "+num1+" and " +num2+" is : "+sum);
}

}
```

my question is how can i linked them and see if its compiles if i dont know whats inside the MainClass.class

i hope my question is clear

Comment: I hate to be the one to say it but no, you're question is not clear.

Comment: If you do have the MainClass.class file, and you do not have the source code, then you can use the Java decompiler (bin\javap) to see what is implemented in your class (i.e. what methods it contains and their signatures).

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend, as Edwin Dalorzo said, to try decompiling the .class. But for what you're doing. You would:

1. Compile App.java "javac App.java"
2. Run MainClass.class "java MainClass"

That will do what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Just recompile App.java and try to run MainClass. You don't need to link it.

Comment: how can i recompile MainClass.class

Comment: You cannot, because you don't have the source

Answer (score 1):

You should have a MainClass.java file and an App.java file. You compile these 2 files and run the MainClass.class file (your driver).

The .class files contain the Java bytecode. They should be linked if the 2 .class files are in the same folder.

Comment: I don't believe he has the MainClass.java. I think he just has the .class.

Comment: i just have the MainClass.class

Comment: Ahh! I see. I misunderstood the question.